# How to use colMean knowing specific rows ID in R

Tags: r

the problem is the following: I have a vector "A" with three values initialized to 0 I have a data frame "B" with lots of values, and each value has a ID number from 1 to 3 Finally I have three different vectors "1", "2" and "3" with the rowsID for each of the values´ID. For example: the first vector "1" is (1,2,3,4) that means that in my data frame "B", the values located in the positions 1,2,3 and 4 all have the ID 1. Now my question is: How can i use the function colMeans in order to calculate the mean of the values that have the ID 1 and save the mean into the first position of the vector "A"?

should be something like this:

```
A <- colMean(sum(B which rowID==values in vector "1"))
```

Comment: Maybe `colMeans(B[rowID %in% vector1])`. Is really `"1"` the name of a vector? If it is, substitute `1` between back quotes for `vector1`.

Comment: No, its just an example, I should have used another name yes

Comment: I dont know why but it does say that rowID object was not found

Comment: What kind of data type do you have? Are those vectors and row ID columns of an object of class `data.frame` (for instance, `B`)? If so use `B[["rowID"]]` and `B[["1"]]`.

Comment: Would it be easier to explain if you posted (a subset of) the actual data?

Comment: A, vector1, vector2, vector3 are just vectors. Meanwhile B is a data.frame that has two attributes: a number and an ID; numbers are random but the ID can be 1,2 or 3. So vector1 has the row numbers of the data.frame B that the IDs are 1; same with vector2 for IDs ==2 and vector3 for IDs==3. I just want to compute the mean of the rows in B with the function colMeans() just for the row numbers that are in the vector1

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use "1" as the name of the vector. Name it `one` instead (or something similar).

Second, `colMean` is unnecessary here. Instead you should use `mean(B$columnName[one])`, where `columnName` is the name of the column with the data you need to average. If your B is a vector as well, use `mean(B[one])`.
To assign it to vector A, you should use `A[1] <- mean(B$columnName[one])`.